# cardinality of collection of chains in the collection of infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ with inclusion partial order

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's confer inclusion partial order in the collection of infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

Is the cardinality of the collection of chains in that poset countable or uncountable?

Comment: What do you think? What do you know about the chains in that partial order?

Comment: What i know is... collection of infinite subsets of natural numbers itself is uncountable, of course.. and..... 
 It is impossible to construct uncountable disjoint collection of subsets of natural numbers..
 
 It seems that collection of chains will, in some sense, saturate the whole $P(\mathbb{N})$ in countable steps.. but it is just my crude feeling..

Comment: @BCLC: I'd be happy to hear what makes this [set-theory] in your eyes.

Answer (score 2):

Uncountable as the collection of infinite subsets of $\mathbb N$ is already uncountable.

Comment: You can actually say much more than just that.

Answer (score 2):

First, recall that in general, a subset of a chain is a chain.

Second, recall (or prove) that there is an uncountable chain in $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ when ordered by inclusion (**HINT:** Find such chain in $\mathcal P(\Bbb Q)$ first), in fact you can find a chain whose cardinality is that of $\Bbb R$. In fact such chain can be order-isomorphic to $\Bbb R$.

Finally, calculate how many chains you can find in $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$.

Comment: I've managed to check that there exists an uncountable chain in $\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{Q})$ which is order-isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ ..